# php passing data form

Tags: php, forms, apache

I use the GET method to pass data from index.php to profile.php

index.php code is

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="profile.php" method="GET">
username: <input type="text" username="user"><br>
password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="alert('task success')"/>click me"</button>

</body>
</html>
```

profile.php code is

```
<?php
    echo " username: "$_GET ['username']."; password "$_GET['pass'];
?>
```

the output is
[image]

it es pass the inputs of the form successfully but I need it to appear in profile.php file

how can I make the output appear in profile.php page?

any help please

Comment: The `input` tag for the username should be `<input type="text" name="username">`.

Comment: In your html code remove the `"` after `click me`and remove the `/` before the `click me` (at the end of `<button>` tag).  In you profile.php change current sentence by this one `echo " username: ".$_GET['username']." password: ".$_GET['pass'];`  And also do the @kenny fix in the other comment.  Too much typos. Use a better editor of code that will help you to fix them, like [Virtual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page is redirected. You will need to send an AJAX request to the action that you want to execute. With jQuery you can prevent a `form` from submitting like this:

```
$('form').submit(function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault(); //prevents the default action

}
```

You will need to [collect the parameters, send them via AJAX and handle the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).